# Field visibility restriction/access control in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, privileges, user-roles

I currently own a MongoDB database that contains a collection named User. User collection has a field called contact_info among several other fields.

My requirement is to allow a member in my team having access to the database with 'admin' role to view contact_info when querying a user, however, a team member with 'developer' role should be able to query a user but not view his/her contact_info (i.e. contact_info key in the user document should be hidden or masked for a team member with 'developer' role). I am looking for a field-level visibility restriction in MongoDB to comply with GDPR standards.

I am comparatively new to MongoDB and did some search for this requirement, but could not find any direct solution for this. Any help with be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could create a view with only the fields needed (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/).

Then I would create an extra user `developer` and 1 extra role `developerRole`

This `developerRole` should only have access to the view created.